# Type LeadPage(Module) is part of the declarations of 2 modules

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular7, ionic4

When we use `modal` in `ionic-angular(same as a angular)` we have to declare the **page/component** in the nearest **Module.ts**

```
async onCreateLead() {
    const modal = await this.mdlCntrl.create({
      component: LeadPage
    });
    return await modal.present();   }
```

i have to use above lead `component` in two differece **Pages(Modules)** . when i try to use “`LeadPage`” in two diffecent **modules error** is raised :

> Type LeadPage is part of the declarations of 2 modules:

How do i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a component as a model in many pages u need to be added in a higher module.

And generate component like map.component.ts and generate a share.module.ts and export map.component.ts in share.module.ts after that import share.module.ts in App.module.ts

and import MapCompoent in your.modue.ts like entryComponents: [MapComponent];

Comment: Can you explain how routing will work in Shared Module?